# In the *Queendom of Sol* series, why was old King Bruno physically aged?

Tags: continuity, queendom-of-sol

I just read #3 and am starting on the final volume.

[image][image: wellstone]
[image][image: crush]

Amazon reminded me that it was March 2004 that I bought (and read) the first two, so maybe my memory is playing tricks...

In the *future* story, Bruno was described as being out of his mind from following a routine for such a long time, *but* his routine included re-faxing himself each day. There were a pair of gates (later described as a transfax) or a single gate to step in and back out, in the garden next to the hut.

No mention was made of anti-aging mods to live healthily without rebuilding the body via the ubiquitous fax technology, until towards the end of #3.  Then Bruno was described as being innthis state, with his teeth worn down to nubs.

But wasn't that *not* the case in #1 or #2, when he was picked up?

Am I missing or mis-remembering something, miss something originally, or is this a change in the plans breaking continuity between volumes?